# Is there an API to fetch tags related to a given tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api, tags, related

I'm interested in making a tool that explores the tags of a site for tags which should be merged or mention each other in tag wikis etc.

On [the page of any given tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automobiles) there is a column on the right of the page, ***Related Tags***.

I would like to be able to access this through the API but I haven't been able to find an API which exposes it. Am I missing something or has it not been proposed?

Comment: This information is not currently exposed by the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related tags were one of the "maybes" slated for API V2.0.

It got [implemented today](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-tags).

Note that our definition of related is pretty much "appears on the same questions as", there's no real secret sauce there.

Comment: No problem. As long as it returns the same as what's in the ***Related Tags*** section it should be great.